# How can i generate mongoid.yml config in Rail 2.3.5?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, mongodb, mongoid

As the title says, how can i generate the default mongoid.yml config file on Rail 2.3.5?

I try to use the ´rails generate mongoid:config´ command but it just generates a new app.

And also, I would like to use has_many in mongoid without embedding the associated model in the same field. I would like them to be in separate fields and associated through a *_id "column". Is that possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't. The master branch of MongoID is only Rails 3 compatible. If you want use mongoID with Rails 2.3.5, you need using the 1.0.x branch of MongoID.

In this version, there are no mongoid generator. You need define you own initializer to connect with MongoDB.

Comment: oh, do you think i should upgrade to 3 then? Is it stable enough. Just started on the application so it shouldnt be to hard to make it Rails 3 compatible. Is it easy to upgrade to the final release of Rails 3 when it arrives?

Comment: if you just started your rails app, go for rails3. I've started my first on in February and also migrated one since and it's getting better every day.

Comment: Rails is a little to beta I think. I start a project with it. But if you are not a experiment Rails developper. I discourage you to try rails 3 beta. It's not really complicated to define you own initializer