# mongoid with rails - Database should be a Mongo::DB, not NilClass"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid

Greetings

I am trying to get Mongoid to work with my Rails app and I am getting 
an error: `"Mongoid::Errors::InvalidDatabase in 'Shipment bol should be 
unique'  Database should be a Mongo::DB, not NilClass"`
I have created the mongoid.yml file in my config directory and have  mongodb running as a daemon.  The config file is like so:

```
defaults: &defaults  
host: localhost 

development:  
  <<: *defaults  
  database: ship-it-development 

test:  
  <<: *defaults  
  database: ship-it-test 

production: 
  <<: *defaults  
  host: <%= ENV['MONGOID_HOST'] %>  
  port: <%= ENV['MONGOID_PORT'] %>  
  database: <%= ENV['MONGOID_DATABASE'] %>
```

All of my specs fail with the above error. I am using rails 2.3.8.

Anyone have ideas?

Comment: Are you running this in Production or development?

Comment: development on my local machine

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like explain on question : [How can i generate mongoid.yml config in Rail 2.3.5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2802087/how-can-i-generate-mongoid-yml-config-in-rail-2-3-5)

The mongoid.yml doesn't works with Rails 2.3.x. It's load automatic only with Rails 3.

You need add an initializer with loading your file and use it to define your database.

By example you can add that in an initializer.

```
mongoid_conf = YAML::load_file(Rails.root.join('config/mongoid.yml'))[Rails.env]

Mongoid.configure do |config|
 config.master = Mongo::Connection.new(mongoid_conf['host'], 
                                       mongoid_conf['port']).db(mongoid_conf['database'])
end
```

Answer (score 3):

Also if your writing your own non rails script and you initialize your models first then you will get this error.

You need to configure the database before initializing the model.

I hit this when writing a gem that used mongoid internally

Test cases hit it as well so put the Mongoid.configure section in your test/helper.rb